# Change projection didn't change position in a vector shape in qgis

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, datum

I got a shape of points and when i save it with another datum and open it again, it stays in the same position. I was hoping for a slight change in position when save from epsg:5361 to epsg:32719.

Comment: Do you create a new file or just set the projection? Have you tried changing your project projection (rightclick on layer)

Comment: is enable on the fly re projections enabled....need more info such as the version you are working with.

Comment: Curlew, i created a new file with the new projection.
Gerald, is Qgis 2.6 and reprojections on the fly are disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both CRS you mention (SIRGAS-Chile / UTM zone 19S and WGS 84 / UTM zone 19S) use the same ellipsoid with towgs84 set to all zero. So they can be regarded as identical.

Apart from that: A point in the map remains on its position, regardless of the CRS you are saving it with. If you use an older CRS with a certain shift to WGS84, like PSAD56 / UTM zone 19S, you get different coordinates, but the point still will remain on the same spot.

If you want to vizualise a shift, either turn `On-the-fly-reprojection` **off**, or enter the same coordinates in both CRS. But the CRS must have different towgs84 parameters, otherwise there is no shift.

Comment: Thanks for the towgs84 explanation, didn't know that. Got more info [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GenParms#towgs84-DatumtransformationtoWGS84)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly why are you doing this and secondly how?

If you are plotting the points based on the 5361 and manually entering their coords then this is their location.  If you wish to load it into a 32719 project then it should go in providing you have enabled on the fly projections in options . settings.

the how, is another question. If you are just right clicking and saving and changing the CRS at this then all is well and good. It should go when you load it in, however, the points may still be recognised as the previous CRS.

Assuming it is saved correctly and there is no need for change then enable on the fly projections should do it.

IF THIS IS NOT RIGHT DO NOT DOWN VOTE>>I WILL DELETE>>INFORMATION IS SPARSE AND THIS IS A BEST GUESS.

Comment: I open a cvs file with the points, the original CRS of that file is 5361, the saved it in a new shp file with CRS 32719. Qgis open this new file automatically, so i can see the points are in identical position.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reprojecting on the fly then QGIS will make it appear in the same place.

It's hard to say more without a better description of what you have and what you are trying to do.